# Wha datatype is "System:VariableValue" in SSIS?

Tags: variables, logging, ssis

I need to log every change of variable values in a SSIS, at package level.
I have a SQL Task Editor that receives, as parameters, System::VariableName and System::VariableValue. I use this parameter to log a line in a DB log table.

Everything is working fine BUT... so far i only have numeric variables so, in the "Parameter Mapping", i specificed that the variable with name "System::VariableValue" is a NUMERIC DataType.

What happens when I will have a Datetime variable or a varchar variable? How can I handle variables of different types in this case?
Thankx

[image: I need to find the correct data type in this list]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the datatype sql_variant, which will accommodate the different datatypes.
More on that here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx

Also, SSIS does have a on variable changed event which maybe helpful for you, though it sounds like you have a good custom solution.
m

EDIT:

So there is some documentation on MSDN that seems to suggest nvarchar maps to sql_variant.  This worked for strings, but left the value empty for numeric values.  Looking at the type for Variable.Value in the variables collection in a script task, it notes the type is empty.  So I tried setting the data type to null, which did not work at all.

Finally, I created a script task to do the job and this worked correctly.  The script task must call a stored proc in order for it to handle all the data types.  I tested it with string, int, double and bool, all of which worked correctly.

Here is the table I used:

```
create table logging (myval sql_variant);
```

Here is the proc definition:

```
Create proc [dbo].[insertLog]
@myVal sql_variant
AS
Begin
set nocount on;
    insert into logging values(@myVal);
end;
```

In the OnVariableValueChanged event handler, I added a script task with the following code:

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
        public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here
            object val = Dts.Variables["System::VariableValue"].Value;
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Dts.Connections[".\\sql2016.Test"].ConnectionString);
            using (conn)
            {
                conn.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("insertLog", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myVal", val);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }


            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

".\sql2016.Test" is the name of the connection manager in the package.
Please see if this will work for you,
m

Comment: Thankx for your time. I didn't know the sql_variant type and this seems useful BUT when I have to choose the DataType for the parameter I can't find a SQL_Variant. The closest match seems "VARIANT_BOOL" that doesnt work at all. On the other hand, I see that "NUMERIC" seems to handle also varchar variables and i can't understand why.

Comment: The datatype in your logging table would be sql_variant, then, regardless of what datatype the variable is, you could still insert the value into the same column.

Comment: In fact your solution is OK for the final SQL Server part. My current problem is, on the other hand, the data type in the dtsx task configuration. The SQL Script task is also asking for a data type for the System::VariableValue and among the possibilites i don't find any suitable "variant". What if my value is a string? OK, the table on the DB, thankx to your suggestion, is ready to receive a string... but the SSIS task could be not. I hope I managed to explain my doubts.

Comment: I wonder if you could update the question with a screenshot which might help to illustrate the point more.  It sounds like you are updating the logging table using a SQL Task.  The variable should be mapped to the datatype that it actually is in the package.  i.e. if it's filename - string, then it should be string in the sql task.

Comment: I added an image. Basically, I need to find the correct item in the dropdown . I am using NUMERIC and it is working, but I suppose it is the wrong value. In My DB , in the log table, I have a simple varchar because in the text of the SQL task I convert System::VariableValue to a Varchar

Comment: I came up with a solution for this, but it's a slightly complicated.  Please see my edit.

Comment: Thankx a lot. Interesting ideas there! I'll give it a try as soon as I can (right now I was forced, for completely different reasons, to refactor everything with Biml). I marked this as a solution because it gave me some ideas to "free my hands" with the logging part.